# UIScrollView crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Has anyone seen this scrollview related crash? I am unable to reproduce this but I have received this on the live build over our analytics tool fabric.

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000192e9bbd0 objc_msgSend + 16
1  UIKit                          0x000000018670f608 -[UIScrollView _getDelegateZoomView] + 80
2  UIKit                          0x000000018699531c -[UIScrollView _offsetForCenterOfPossibleZoomView:withIncomingBoundsSize:] + 64
3  UIKit                          0x0000000186d81f34 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _nsis_center:bounds:inEngine:] + 1208
4  UIKit                          0x00000001867bc9d8 -[UIView(Geometry) _applyISEngineLayoutValues] + 160
5  UIKit                          0x00000001866d6554 -[UIView(Geometry) _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 276
6  UIKit                          0x00000001866d1b18 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 712
7  MyAppDetailCell                0x00000001000f29e0 -[MyAppDetailCell displayDataDelayed:] (MyAppDetailCell.m:139)
8  Foundation                     0x0000000182d9cba4 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 424
9  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181e6ac20 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
10 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181e6a8d0 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 888
11 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181e6831c __CFRunLoopRun + 1372
12 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000181d951f4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
13 GraphicsServices               0x000000018b1b76fc GSEventRunModal + 168
14 UIKit                          0x000000018672610c UIApplicationMain + 1488
15 MyApp                          0x00000001000f66f4 main (main.m:16)
16 libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000193506a08 start + 4
```

Because of the company policy, I cannot upload the code here. I am doing some animation (SpriteKit), modifying some constraints and mostly doing UI updates in that displayDataDelayed method, but not touching the scrollview in this method. I anticipate that layoutIfNeeded after some constraint updates might have been causing this. But again unable to reproduce this. We had 12M sessions of the app since last update in 4 days and this occurred 1k times, hence it is definitely not easily reproducible.

Comment: Update your question with the related code (the method that includes MyAppDetailCell.m line 139).

Comment: Add details on what interactions the crash happens.
Is it crashing when you are navigating to another view?

Comment: @Abhinav please explain question in brief and provide your code.

Comment: check that this method **MyAppDetailCell** contains any data is missing or not

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. It worked for me

```
self.scrollView.delegate = nil;
self.scrollView = nil;
```

Does not make much sense i'm using ARC but it worked for me.

Also check if view controller of scrollview's superview is weak reference. That may also be an issue. Good luck.

Comment: I dont thinks so its this, delegate handling has already been done in dealloc. :(

Comment: Then profiling for zombies is the last resort. Profile for zombies, let it crash and then there will be a pop up with  small arrow on it, hitting on which will take you to the stack where you can see what was deallocated.